# When using 'Generator', This error occured "expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors"

Tags: python, keras

I created a generator as below, also tensorflow model.
But when train, Error happend and I coun't know how to fix

```py
def our_generator():
    for i in range(1000):
        x = np.random.rand(28, 28)
        y = np.random.rand(28, 28)
        z = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=1)
        yield x, y, z

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(our_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int16),         output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape(\[28, 28\]), tf.TensorShape(\[28, 28\]), tf.TensorShape(\[1\])))

from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, concatenate, Dropout
input_1 = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
input_1_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_1)
output_1 = Model(inputs=input_1,  outputs=input_1_1)
input_2 = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
input_2_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_2)
output_2 = Model(inputs=input_2,  outputs=input_2_1)
result = concatenate(\[output_1.output, output_2.output\])
temp_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(result)
output\_ = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(temp_1)
model = Model(inputs=\[output_1.input, output_2.input\],  outputs=output\_)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),  metrics=\['accuracy'\])

history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

```
"ValueError: Layer "model_26" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: \[\<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 28, 28) dtype=float32\>\]

Generator : 3 output
Tensorflow : 2 input and 1 output
```